# Common methods for proving: Existence proof

Tags: logic, proof-verification, proof-writing

For every real number x with  $x\neq -1$ there exists a real number y such that $ \frac{y}{y+1}=x $.

$ \forall x\in \Bbb R\setminus (1) \ \ \exists y \in \Bbb R : \frac{y}{y+1}=x \\, x \neq -1 $

$ So \ \ if \ \ I \ \ choose \ \ e.g. \ x= \frac{1}{2} \ \ then \ \ y=1  \ \ such \ \ that \ \ \frac{y}{y+1}=x $

Is this a correct way of proving this?

Comment: No. You are supposed to prove it for _every_ $x$, and not for only one specific choice of $x$. So choosing $x=\frac{1}{2}$ does not qualify as the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at one example does not prove a universal statement.  Note that the statement is to be proven true for every $x\ne 1$.  You have only shown it to be true for one specific real number.

Your approach should be:  Given an arbitrary $x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{1\}$ find a $y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x=\frac{y}{y+1}$ (which amounts to solving for $y$).

Leave $x$ as $x$...do not assign it a specific value.

Comment: Solving for y : y = x(y+1) . I am not sure how to prove the general case...

Comment: Expand the right hand side, then separate the $y$ terms to one side and solve.

Comment: Solving for y : $  \frac{x}{1-x}=y $ then $ \frac{\frac{x}{1-x}}{\frac{x}{1-x}+1}=x $ Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the transformation of $y\rightarrow z-1$ to change it to for all $x\neq 1$ there exists $z$ such that $\frac{z-1}{z}=1-\frac{1}{z}=x$, which is easily solvable for $z$ in terms of $x$.

Comment: Solving $ \frac{z-1}{z}=1-\frac{1}{z}=x $ for  z in terms of x  yields $ \frac{-1}{x-1}=z $ . I am not sure how to make a general case of this.

Comment: It yields $\frac{1}{x-1}=z$, so substituting back in $z=y+1$, we get that $y=\frac{1}{x-1}-1=\frac{-x}{x-1}$, so we found such a $y$ for a given $x$.